# Nginx security with SSL not blocking Postman/Http client requests

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, nginx, postman

I have Nginx with ssl setup which is working well. I use it as a proxy server for my nodejs server. I only have SSL in Nginx and not Nodejs spp.

**Issue:** Postman and other HTTP clients can still make post requests without SSL cert. This nodejs server is for both android client and web client, must I implement SSL to nodejs server(Application level) directly too? like below:

```js
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');

// const httpsOptions = {cert, ca, key};
const app = express();
const httpsServer = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app);
httpsServer.listen(443, 'exampledomain.com');
```

Flutter apps are also able to make request to the server without SSL. Meaning this server is still insecure.

How do I prevent HTTP clients from accessing the server without SSL?

Comment: Can you post your nginx config ? Your node server has not to be run/listening on https. any other port that does not conflict with nginx is absolut fine. The client reach first your nginx over http/https and nginx "forward" the request to your node.js (which listen on what ever port you want) You have "redirect" all clients that connect via http on the nginx to https

Answer (score 0):

By default postman always will post requests with SSL certificate, make sure that you turned the SSL verification off in Settings.

[POSTMAN SETTINGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P84Mq.png)

Maybe your code is already working, but you are misleading the test.